# Chemnum: Chapter-related numbering?

Tags: numbering, chemnum

First of all, I just started with LaTeX. So far, I got everything working, including [`chemnum`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemnum).

However, I want to split my thesis into chapters. Numbering of the compounds is supposed to be 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 etc. Next chapter, it starts with 2.1, 2.2, 2.3.

Is there a way to do this with [`chemnum`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemnum)? Could not find anything.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This kind of numbering is actually not taken into account by `chemnum`. It actually seems strange to me: should the same compound have different numbers in different chapters?

Comment: Sorry, I did not think a MWE could be useful here. In case of the identical compound in different chapters, the numbering should be the same. Example: Compound is introduced in Chapter 1 as 1.4, and would be labelled in Chapter 3 as 1.4.

Comment: `\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\cmpdref{cmpd1}
\cmpdref{cmpd2}
\includegraphics{test.eps}
\caption{\cmpd{cmpd1} and \cmpd{cmpd2}}
\end{figure}
%I want this to give 1.1 and 1.2
\chapter{Two}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\cmpdref{cmpd1}
\cmpdref{cmpd2}
\includegraphics{test.eps}
\caption{\cmpd{cmpd1} and \cmpd{cmpd2}}
\end{figure}
%This should give 2.1 and 2.2`

Comment: @cgnieder I've seen this done, and while I would not recommend it there are people who like it. (I don't like per-chapter numbering at all.)

Comment: @JosephWright Hm, I should probably implement this then... `chemnum` needs some polishing anyway...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Supplement 2014/03/14:**

Two days ago v1.0 of `chemnum` was released. There have been various changes. One of them is a built-in possibility for a case like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{chemnum}

\makeatletter
% new counter format for chemnum:
\newcmpdcounterformat{chapter}{\thechapter.\@arabic}
\makeatother

\setchemnum{
  counter-within = chapter ,
  counter-format = chapter % use new counter format
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\cmpd{a} and \cmpd{b}

\chapter{Second}
\cmpd{a} and \cmpd{c}

\end{document}
```

---

**Original answer:**

A temporary solution based on [Heiko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128708/5049):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{chemnum}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \int_to_chapter:n
  { \thechapter . \int_to_arabic:n }

% add the new choice to the options:
\keys_define:nn { chemnum }
  {
    cmpd-counter .generate_choices:n =
      { arabic , alph , Alph , greek, Greek , roman , Roman , Symbol , chapter }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% choose the new option:
\cmpdsetup{cmpd-counter=chapter}

% reset counter every new chapter:    
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\chapter{\cmpdreset}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\cmpd{a} and \cmpd{b}

\chapter{Second}
\cmpd{a} and \cmpd{c}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This actually works! Thanks to all of you :)

Answer (score 3):

A hack to add the chapter number:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{chemnum}

\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \catcode`\_=11 %
  \catcode`\:=11 %
  \global\let\org@cmpd\cmpd
  \gdef\cmpd#1{%
    \begingroup
      \cmpdsetup{cmpd-counter=Symbol}%
      \def\int_to_Symbol:n{%
        \thechapter.\int_to_arabic:n
      }%
      \org@cmpd{#1}%
    \endgroup
  }%
  % reset numbers at chapters
\@firstofone{\endgroup
  \let\c@chemnum@counter\g__chemnum_cmpd_int
  \@addtoreset{chemnum@counter}{chapter}%
}
\endgroup

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\cmpd{a} and \cmpd{b}
\chapter{Second}
\cmpd{a} and \cmpd{c}
\end{document}
```

Result:

> Chapter 1: **1.1** and **1.2**
>    Chapter 2: **1.1** and **2.1**

Comment: +1 Nice idea :) The counter is not reset at chapters, though. The code thus gives *2.3* instead of *2.1*.

Comment: Thanks! But indeed, it gives 2.3. Also do I have some additional Output like "1.1 cmpd1 1.1 cmpd2 1.1", and I don't know where that is coming from. Might as well be a mistake by me due to the lack of experience...